# I'm getting different test results in Docker compared to a local run

Tags: django, docker, pytest

In the following branch of my project I'm implementing various tests, at the moment:
https://github.com/Nebucatnetzer/network_inventory/tree/tests

When I ran pytest locally the tests are passing save for one, which isn't the problem.
When I ran the tests with `make test` the tests are run inside the Docker container and roughly 50% of all the tests are failing.
I can't figure out why this is happening.
As far as I can tell the settings for both projects are the same and when I start the Docker container normally and do the tests by hand they seem to work just fine.

I'm stuck on this since a few days and just don't understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
When I was running the tests locally I was using a SQLite DB in RAM. I used hardcoded primary keys in the URLs I wanted to test. This worked fine with SQLite however failed for some reason with the Postgres DB in the Docker container.
I fixed now all the URLs so that they are using the PK directly from the object I created for the test and all tests are passing now.